# Gorm Create Error with Form-Data File Upload

Tags: postgresql, go, multipartform-data, go-gorm

I'm trying to create a record in a PostgreSQL server. The request comes to me as file data in multipart format. After uploading the file to my end, I call gorm.Create, but it throws an error.

When I comment out the file upload part, the error disappears, but I need to upload the file.

here is my controller part:

```golang
func (pc ProductController) Create(c *gin.Context) {

    var product migrations.Product

    if err := c.Bind(&product); err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error(), "message": "İşlem başarısız. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz veya sistem yöneticinize başvurun. Hata kodu: PD-CRT-01"})
        return
    }

    if product.Name == "" {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": "Name is required", "message": "İşlem başarısız. Lütfen Ad Alanını Boş Bırakmayınız. Hata kodu: PD-CRT-02"})
        return
    }

    if product.Price == 0 {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": "Price is required", "message": "İşlem başarısız. Lütfen Fiş Değeri Alanını Boş Bırakmayınız. Hata kodu: PD-CRT-03"})
        return
    }
    if product.ID != 0 {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": "Remove ID field", "message": "Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz veya sistem yöneticinize başvurun. Hata kodu: PD-CRT-ID-01"})
        return
    }

    file, err := c.FormFile("image")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error(), "message": "Lütfen Resim Ekleyiniz. Hata kodu: PD-CRT-IMG-01"})
    }
    fileName := time.Now().Format("20060102150405") + "-" + strings.Split(file.Filename, ".")[0] + "." + strings.Split(file.Filename, ".")[1]
    dst := fmt.Sprintf("./public/images/%s", fileName)
    err = c.SaveUploadedFile(file, dst)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error(), "message": "Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz veya sistem yöneticinize başvurun. Hata kodu: PD-CRT-IMG-02"})
        return
    }

    product.Image = &migrations.File{
        Path:      fileName,
        Extension: strings.Split(file.Filename, ".")[1],
    }
    log.Println(product)
    err = db.Conn.Create(&product).Error
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error(), "message": "İşlem başarısız. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz veya sistem yöneticinize başvurun. Hata kodu: PD-CRT-04"})
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"message": "Ürün başarıyla eklendi.", "data": product})
    return
}
```

And my request:

[image: request]

The Error:

```json
{
    "error": "strconv.ParseInt: parsing \"products\": invalid syntax; strconv.ParseInt: parsing \"products\": invalid syntax",
}
```

There are my structs:

```golang
type Order struct {
    ID         uint       `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    UserID     int        `gorm:"index" json:"user_id"`
    RoomNo     int        `gorm:"comment:oda_no" json:"room_no"`
    IsDone     bool       `gorm:"default:false" json:"is_done"`
    StatusCode int        `gorm:"default:0" json:"status_code"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time  `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time  `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt  time.Time  `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    Products   []*Product `gorm:"many2many:orders_products" json:"products,omitempty"`
}

type Product struct {
    ID        uint      `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id" form:"id"`
    Name      string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255)" json:"name" form:"name"`
    Price     float64   `gorm:"type:decimal(10,2)" json:"price" form:"price"`
    IsActive  bool      `gorm:"default:true" json:"is_active" form:"isActive"`
    Image     File      `gorm:"polymorphic:Module" json:"image,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" form:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" form:"updatedAt"`
    DeletedAt time.Time `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
}

type OrdersProduct struct {
    OrderID   int `gorm:"index" json:"order_id"`
    ProductID int `gorm:"index" json:"product_id"`
    Count     int `gorm:"default:0" json:"count"`
}


type File struct {
    ID         uint      `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt  time.Time `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    Path       string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255)" json:"path"`
    Extension  string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255)" json:"extension"`
    ModuleID   int       `gorm:"type:integer" json:"module_id"`
    ModuleType int       `gorm:"type:integer" json:"module_type"`
}
```

Comment: When I remove the image upload section, it successfully saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the File struct's unit types. strconv.ParseInt() converts strings to values. ModuleID, ModuleType or both have to be string i think.